# OpenERP Report Designer server connection error

Tags: report, odoo, rml

In order to modify an openerp report i installed openoffice plugin to connect to openerp `.sxw` files

Once installed I do the following:

1. I set the server parameter in order to connect to a remote server
   Server: mydomain.co
   Port:443
   Protocol Connection: XML-RPC secure (due to the server listen through 443 port https)
2. click on next
3. Set the following parameters

Database: `mydbname`

login: admin (openerp user not db user)

Password: mypassword

When clicking on the connect button I get the following error:

`Connection denied: Enter a valid login/password`

I'm sure the login and password are correct, any hint to solve this issue?

Regards,

Comment: what is version of your open office?

Comment: Hi Freddy, the answer is 4.0.1